# Prove that $\pi:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\cong S^2$ is a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space, spheres, hopf-fibration

I have to solve this one:

> Let us consider the sphere $S^3\subset \mathbb{R}^4\cong\mathbb{C}^2$, and the map $\pi:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\cong S^2$ defined as the projection's restriction $(z_1,z_2)\mapsto [z_1:z_2]$. Prove that $\pi$ is a submersion.

Solution:

I identify $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ and $S^2$ through a diffeomorphism

\begin{array}{crcl}
f:& \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}) & \longrightarrow & S^2 \\
& [z_1,z_2] & \longmapsto & \frac{1}{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2}\big(|z_2|^2-|z_1|^2,2z_1\overline{z_2} \big)
\end{array}

This way we have

\begin{array}{crcl}
f\circ\pi:& S^3 & \longrightarrow & S^2 \\
& (z_1,z_2) & \longmapsto & \big(|z_2|^2-|z_1|^2,2z_1\overline{z_2} \big)
\end{array}

because $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$. Now we compute the Jacobian matrix of $f\circ\pi$

\begin{equation}
J_{f\circ\pi}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2\overline{z_2} & 2z_1\frac{2|z_2|z_2-|z_2|^2}{z_2^2} \\
2|z_1| & -2|z_2|
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
that has full rank, so $f\circ\pi$ is a submersion.

Now the thing is: how can I conclude that $\pi$ is a submersion?

Any other idea to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: **Hint:** $f^{-1} \circ f \circ \pi= \pi$

Comment: Great idea. But how can I prove that $f^{-1}$ is a submersion? Could you show me the expression of $f^{-1}(x,y,z)$ with $(x,y,z)\in S^2$?

Comment: $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: $f$ is a diffeomorphism so $f_*$ is an isomorphism, and then $f$ is both an immersion and a submersion. The same can be said for $f^{-1}$. I get it, thank you

Comment: Is it possible to show that $\pi$ is a submersion without using this $f$?

Comment: Yes, but I guess it depends on your prerequisites if you like the proof. You can obtain $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ equally well as the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^3$ by the multiplication action of $\mathbb{S}^1$ on $\mathbb{S}^3$. This action is free and proper (freeness is easy to check, proper because all spaces are compact), hence there exists a unique smooth structure on $\mathbb{S}^3/\mathbb{S}^1$ s.t. the projection is a submersion. You can find the proof of this general fact (any proper, free group action of a Lie group on a manifold) in Lee's book for example.

Comment: I know nothing about actions on groups, so I think I have a different prerequisites than yours. My question was easier than that. I'm afraid that the solution I gave for this exercise is not right because I used Hopf's map, which is not involved in the course I'm attending. So I ask, is there a way to compute the Jacobian matrix of $\pi:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ defined by $(z,w)\mapsto [z:w]$, without involving $f$? Thanks

Comment: What do you already know about $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ without using $f$?  For example, do you already know it's dimension $2$?  If so, it's enough to show that the kerenl of $\pi_\ast|_S^3$ is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: @JasonDeVito yes I know it's 2-dimensional, but I don't understand why it is enough. Can you show me your steps?

Comment: Your derivatives don't make much sense and you should have a $2\times 3$ matrix for the derivative, once you work in charts.  Here's an alternative suggestion. Consider the map $g\colon\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C$ given by $g(z_1,z_2)=z_2/z_1$. Show that this is a submersion (officially you need to think about this in real coordinates — can you justify getting around that?). Now what does it take to see that the restriction to $S^3$ is still a submersion?  How is $\ker dg_z$ related to $T_zS^3$?

Comment: @Andrew:  Sorry about the typesetting in the previous comment, I meant $\pi_\ast|_{S^3}$.  The idea is that for $p \in S^3$, $\pi_\ast |_p:T_p S^3\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is a map between a $3$-dim vector space and a $2$-dim vector space.  Being a submerion means this map is a surjection; but by basic linear algebra this occurs iff the kernel of $\pi_\ast$ is $1$-dimensional at each point.